# How to restrict which Google Home devices can interact with an action?

Tags: actions-on-google

I want to build a Conversation Action for Google Home device and control its access. Only certain devices can invoke some actions. How can this be done, once the agent is publicly deployed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think of Google Home the same way you would think about a web browser and an Action the same as a web page or site. If you wanted to limit what web browsers can access a public site on the Internet, you're somewhat limited.

You could restrict access to certain IP addresses, and this will work in some cases - but it means that access via non-static IP addresses aren't possible, and if (ie - when) a machine gets a new static IP address, you have a lot of work to do. Similarly, the Google Home device can send a random [user_id](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/conversation#User) string for each unique user, and you can use this to limit who has access. But this string can change by the user resetting their Google Home device, and when it does, you will have to deal with that.

A better solution on the web is to allow people to log into your site. This way you can have a public facing web page, but only people with accounts can access. You can determine how to hand out accounts, so this is very flexible. The equivalent with Google Home is [Account Linking](https://developers.google.com/actions/develop/identity/account-linking) where you will maintain an account as part of an OAuth2 system that you control. Google Home will ask for permission to access your system, and you will issue OAuth2 tokens to Actions - these tokens will be passed back to you for each request, and you can verify that the user has access.

I strongly suggest going with the [Authorization Code Flow](https://developers.google.com/actions/develop/identity/oauth2-code-flow) since this seems to be where Google is focusing on providing additional features - such as signing up to your service through Google Home.

Comment: Thanks A LOT for your answer. You made the authorization process crystal clear to me. I will study the code flow as you suggested.

Comment: Glad this has put you on the right track. Dont' hesitate to open up new questions if you have issues along the way. If you find the answer helps, please upvote and/or accept it.